# Blur alpha channel in image in PHP/Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

Consider the following snippet, where I'm trying to create an image of an opaque red square fading out into a mostly-transparent blue square.

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(300, 300, '#0000ff22');

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#ff0000ff');
$draw->rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);

$image->drawImage($draw);
$image->blurImage(25,23);

$image->setImageFormat("png");
header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
echo $image;
```

The output instead looks like the red and blue channels are getting blurred, but not the alpha channel. I've tried manually specifiying CHANNEL_ALPHA to the blurImage's third parameter, but it had no effect. I'm using version 6.6.2-6 of ImageMagick (and the PHP extension is compiled against that version).

[image: this]

Comment: Blurring the alpha will make no difference as everything is within the image - it won't blur the red area against the blue, only the whole image against nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what I think you're asking for:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(300, 300, '#0000ff22');

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#ff0000ff');
$draw->rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);

$image->drawImage($draw);
$image->blurImage(25,23, imagick::COLOR_RED);

$image->setImageFormat("png");
header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
echo $image;
?>
```

This only works because the the thing we're blurring is pure red; it's not a general solution. A more general solution would create a separate image, blur it, then composite it over the background.